# Spring Data with mongodb query to bring some elements from the array

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data

I'm trying to bring several items from an array into an object, but the result is just one item from that array. What I want is to bring several items from this array.

I have:

```
{
"title": "market",
"products": [
             {"name": "pepperoni pizza"},
             {"name": "mozzarella pizza"},
             {"name": "yogurt"},
             {"name": "soda"},
            ] 
}
```

And:

```
Query query = new Query();
        query.fields().elemMatch("products", Criteria.where("name").regex("pizza", "i"))
                .include("products")
                .include("title");
        mongoTemplate.find(query, Business.class);
```

Outcome:

```
{
"title": "market",
"products": [
             {"name": "pepperoni pizza"}
            ] 
}
```

But I want:

```
{
"title": "market",
"products": [
             {"name": "pepperoni pizza"},
             {"name": "mozzarella pizza"}
            ] 
}
```

Comment: The query is behaving as it is expected. This is because you are using the [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/index.html) projection operator. From the definition, it limits the contents of an array field from the query results to contain _only the first element_ matching the `$elemMatch` condition. To filter the way you are expecting you have to use an aggregation query with `$filter`.

Answer (score 1):

can't help with spring data version but this is the mongo query it should be generating:

```java
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            'products.name': /pizza/i
        }
    },
    {
        $set: {
            products: {
                $filter: {
                    input: "$products",
                    cond: { $regexMatch: { input: "$$this.name", regex: /pizza/i } }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```